# Difference between .CreateNdefMessageCallback and CreateBeamUrisCallback

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

What is the Difference between in CreateNdefMessageCallback and  CreateBeamUrisCallback
when dealing with NFC.

I tried to send data using CreateNdefMessageCallback only

Answer (score 0):

No difference, they are both deprecated and removed from Android 10+

Before that one sent an NDef message just via NFC (CreateNdefMessageCallback) and the other used NFC to setup a Bluetooth connection to send data.

Comment: can I still use it even if they are deprecated? or there is an alternative

Comment: You cannot use them in Android 10 and above as the functionality behind them was removed, the recommended alternative is to use Bluetooth or Wifi Direct (or Google "Nearby"). Please have shown it possible to also use Host Card Emulation to send messages via NFC but this is complicated. But I found using NFC to send data was far too unreliable, wifi direct is better.